# Append a list to the value for matching key values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have the following 2 rows in my csv:

```
0000001,0,-94.8,28
0000001,6,-95.4,28
```

Let's say that `source_id 0000001` corresponds to the `event_id 123456`, that's what the following lines of code are doing:

```
source_id = row[0].lstrip("0")
if source_id in sourceid_eventid_dict:
    event_id = sourceid_eventid_dict[source_id]
```

After reading the two rows of csv in I need to get the following dictionary set.

```
{123456: [[-94.8, 28], [-95.4, 28]}
```

My current code is as follows:

```
model_dev_coordinate_dict = dict()    
# create dict of eventid, coordinates from model dev csv
with open(model_dev_file, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        source_id = row[0].lstrip("0")
        if source_id in sourceid_eventid_dict:
            event_id = sourceid_eventid_dict[source_id]
            model_dev_coordinate_dict.setdefault(event_id, []).append([row[2], row[3]])
```

My code is creating a new key, value pair each time as opposed to using the existing key to append the new list to the existing value.

Comment: Your code actually looks fine. Why do you use `newline=''` in `open`?

Comment: Not entirely sure, it was in all of the examples.

Comment: Have you tried remove this option? Or change it to `newline='\n'`

Comment: Just did, not quite sure what I'm meant to be looking for?

Comment: Does it work now after changing the option?

Comment: don't think it does, I have another dictionary that I'm meant to be comparing to, but when I try and compare with that I cannot find a single match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95114/discussion-between-user4659009-and-anthony-kong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After reading the two rows of csv in I need to get the following dictionary set.
>   `{123456: [[-94.8, 28], [-95.4, 28]}`.

For this, you can use the [*csv*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to parse the input, [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to separate the *source_id* from the *data* on each row, a simple dict to convert a *source_id* to *event_id*, and [*dict.setdefault()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) with *list.append* to take care of the data aggregation.

```
import csv
import pprint

s = '''\
0000001,0,-94.8,28
0000001,6,-95.4,28
0000002,7,-97.6,29
'''.splitlines()

event_map = {'0000001': '123456', '0000002': '789012'}

groupdict = {}
for row in csv.reader(s):
    source_id = row[0]
    event_id = event_map[source_id]
    data = row[1:]
    groupdict.setdefault(event_id, []).append(data)
pprint.pprint(groupdict)
```

The above code outputs:

```
{'123456': [['0', '-94.8', '28'], ['6', '-95.4', '28']],
 '789012': [['7', '-97.6', '29']]}
```

Comment: Nice answer. But the numbers are still strings. Should be ints and floats.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Here is the whole code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

fobj = io.StringIO("""
0000001,0,-94.8,28
0000001,6,-95.4,28
0000002,7,-97.6,29
""")

event_map = {'0000001': '123456', '0000002': '789012'}

df = pd.read_csv(fobj, header=None, index_col=0, 
                 converters={0: lambda k: event_map[k]})
res = {k: df.ix[k].values.tolist() for k in df.index.unique()}
```

Now in steps.

Starting with sample data:

```
fobj = io.StringIO("""
0000001,0,-94.8,28
0000001,6,-95.4,28
0000002,7,-97.6,29
""")
event_map = {'0000001': '123456', '0000002': '789012'}
```

Imports:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

Reading becomes a one-liner:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fobj, header=None, index_col=0, 
                 converters={0: lambda k: event_map[k]})
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)

        1     2   3
0                  
123456  0 -94.8  28
123456  6 -95.4  28
789012  7 -97.6  29
```

Use `.ix[]` to access one event:

```
print(df.ix['123456'])
        1     2   3
0                  
123456  0 -94.8  28
123456  6 -95.4  28
```

You can also convert the entry into a list:

```
>>> df.ix['123456'].values.tolist()
[[0.0, -94.8, 28.0], [6.0, -95.4, 28.0]]
```

of course you can convert your result into a dictionary:

```
>>> {k: df.ix[k].values.tolist() for k in df.index.unique()}
{123456: [[0.0, -94.8, 28.0], [6.0, -95.4, 28.0]], 
 789012: [7.0, -97.6, 29.0]}
```